# Unable to Download npm Packages After Installing Node.js v20.10.0 LTS - 'npm install' Command Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, command-line-interface, node-modules

I've recently downloaded the latest LTS version of Node.js, which is Node.js v20.10.0. After this, I'm not able to download any npm packages with the 'npm install' command.
It is showing this error message in terminal

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../../package.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Hasan Khan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\es6\validate-engines.js
- C:\Users\Hasan Khan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
- C:\Users\Hasan Khan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hasan Khan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\es6\validate-engines.js:8:49)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Hasan Khan\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\es6\\validate-engines.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Hasan Khan\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Hasan Khan\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v20.10.0
```

I tried to reinstall Node.js, and even attempted to download the previous version, Node.js 18, which was working fine before. However, now the 18th version is not working. How can I fix this error?

Comment: It couldnt find the package json file, could you show us the project directory structure?

Comment: Seems like you have executed the command in the wrong directory or you have moved your package.json

Comment: i used express-generator to create my project directory and im 100% sure that i was on the right directory.

Comment: I do have similar issues, but not exactly the same. Are you behind a corporate proxy, and used an older node / npm version before you updated to the latest LTS version? I experience if I first install the packages with an older version, and then a new build with the 20.10.0 version the install succeeds. 
In your case about the roaming npm folder, I've seen an issue somewhere at npm's github. Let me search it

Comment: @HasanKhan, see https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/7089